# Проблема с обновлением версии Serilog.Sinks.Console

Tags: c#, .net, логирование

При обновлении версии библиотеки Serilog.Sinks.Console с версии 3.1.1 на более высокую версию (4.0.0 или 4.0.1) на Blazor Server .NET 6 возникает ошибка при запуске(при билде все норм) сервиса:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration Serilog.ConsoleLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Console(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSinkConfiguration, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel, System.String, System.IFormatProvider, Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch, System.Nullable`1<Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel>, Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.ConsoleTheme)'.
   at Serilog.ColoredConsoleLoggerConfigurationExtensions.ColoredConsole(LoggerSinkConfiguration sinkConfiguration, LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel, String outputTemplate, IFormatProvider formatProvider, LoggingLevelSwitch levelSwitch, Nullable`1 standardErrorFromLevel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.CallConfigurationMethods(ILookup`2 methods, IList`1 configurationMethods, Object receiver)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.ApplySinks(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.Configure(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
   at Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSettingsConfiguration.Settings(ILoggerSettings settings)
   at Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Configuration(LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration, String sectionName, DependencyContext dependencyContext)
   at Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Configuration(LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration, DependencyContext dependencyContext)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\<UserName>\repos\<ProjectDirectory>\src\<ProjectName>\Program.cs:line 52
```

Также подключены следующие библиотеки:

1. Serilog.Sinks.ColoredConsole 3.0.
2. Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile 3.3.0

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем связана данная проблема обновления версии и как ее решить?

Comment: Вы можете текст исключения вставить как есть? Без вот этих ручных переносов, которые в принципе делают трассировку стека нечитабельной. И не надо пложалуйста оформлять цитатой, оформите как блок кода.

Comment: @aepot поправил и вставил, как есть (как и первом случае, цитирование добавляет переносы)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникала, потому что функционал Serilog.Sinks.ColoredConsole переехал в Serilog.Sinks.Console. Serilog.Sinks.ColoredConsole больше не поддерживается. Вот пример:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Verbose().WriteTo.Console(theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Colored).CreateLogger();
```